# windows-1252 to euc-kr encoding

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding, byte

From other windows applications, I got this text `Æ÷¸µÄ«µå` and the equivalent of this text is `포링카드`

You can actually generate it here https://r12a.github.io/apps/encodings/ find attached image below this description.

Further more, I tried this in my code, copying the same logic on that tool.

```
$windows = mb_convert_encoding('Æ÷¸µÄ«µå', 'windows-1252', 'utf-8');
$euc_kr = mb_convert_encoding($windows, 'euc-kr');

echo $euc_kr;exit;
```

But I'm getting this kind of output:

`???????`

So I tried to compare `echo ($euc_kr === '포링카드') ? 'Yes' : 'No';` but still returning `No`

[image: Reference of the tool]

Comment: I guess that your webserver is telling the browser to display the data as UTF-8 while you are outputting a different encoding. Have you tried to echo($windows); ? Also, which encoding is the PHP file written in?

Comment: @PhilippGrassl, actually I die dump `$windows` and returning the same output, since I have a database record containing all the unicode and files which is written in Korean, That's why I'm planning to extract the unicode so I could easily find the file and store/update in the DB. I actually tried to modified `header()` just incase, but still no chance.

Comment: Since you can do a `echo ($euc_kr === '포링카드') ? 'Yes' : 'No';` I suppose your script is written in unicode. Could you open that script in a suited editor like eg. Notepad++ and convert the file to ASCII encoding? It could be that the "Æ÷¸µÄ«µå" is actually UTF-8 encoded and not Windows-1252 in the file.

Comment: I'm using Sublime, yes you're correct, it is UTF-8, but do I need to change my code?

Comment: Actually I think this is a different problem. You want to interpret the characters as korean and write them as UTF-8 into the database. So doing a `mb_convert_encoding('Æ÷¸µÄ«µå', 'utf-8, 'euc-kr');` should be enough, given that 'Æ÷¸µÄ«µå' is not UTF-8 encoded. If it is UTF-8 encoded you would have to do an additional `mb_convert_encoding('Æ÷¸µÄ«µå', 'windows-1252');` before the other call.

Comment: What the heck, `mb_convert_encoding('Æ÷¸µÄ«µå', 'utf-8', 'euc-kr')` is working well! Thanks @PhilippGrassl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think this is a different problem. You want to interpret the characters as korean and write them as UTF-8 into the database. So doing a

```
mb_convert_encoding('Æ÷¸µÄ«µå', 'utf-8, 'euc-kr');
```

should be enough, given that 'Æ÷¸µÄ«µå' is not UTF-8 encoded. If it is UTF-8 encoded you would have to do an additional

```
mb_convert_encoding('Æ÷¸µÄ«µå', 'windows-1252');
```

before the other call.